# preload images off screen - Android browser

Tags: css, android-browser, image-preloader

Is there a way to preload ~3 images that are currently off screen in the android browser.

Currently I'm using an iframe to allow for horizontal scrolling of a banner of images, but when the user scrolls to fast you get a half cut of image until it stops scrolling and loads the image.

I was hoping to pre-render more then about 300px (what it does now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to look in to lazy loading images with Javascript or JQuery. Basicallt the idea is to load image once the DOM has been loaded, this way all images are loaded in full and without hinderence to the page speed.

Take a look at this article.

http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/lazy-loading-images-with-jquery/22

Comment: My issue isn't with page load speed but with how Androids browser only loads about 300px of an image thats offscreen horizontally.